# how can I change column names with out Impact on already maked powerpivot/dinamic tables?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

Just a question? I've maked on Excel a dinamic tables with some DDBB, and the column's names were in Spanish. I need to translate those fields inot another languages, for the rest of foreing customers, butwhen I do that, my dinamic tables desappears. Is ther anyway to change column's titles keeping the dinamic tables? 
In the same way, I have same problema with Excel pivot, I've already created a file with so many differents results for my spanish customers, but I need to créate same files for my foreing customers, with the title of the columns in their languages, Is there any way to changge only the titles keeping the graphics,...…….as they have been defined in spanish file? 
thanks in advance, BR

Answer (score 0):

imho you can only change the column names of your pivots (manually or by code). Changing your datasource will result into the fields dissapearing from the pivottable.

you could make a config file and according to the mapping between column name and language, you can change the caption of you pivotfield in code  ( pivotField.Caption).
be aware the names have to be unique, also I had troubles with columnnames longer than 18 characters

Comment: if it answered your question, could you mark it as answer?  thanks!